# if alerted yes marker won't set

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to make an `if` statement that has an `alert` function.

However if I don't use the `localstorage` function the `alert` box will keep popping up but changes the marker.

If `if` do use the `localstorage` function the marker won't set the color.

Any ideas on what to do?

All help is appreciated.

```
var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
if (alerted != 'yes') {
    if (value.squawk == "7500" || value.squawk == "7600" ||value.squawk == "7700") {
        console.log(value.hex + " is squawking " + value.squawk);
        alert(value.hex + " is squawking " + value.squawk + ". This is usually an error in transponder transmission please DO NOT alert the local authorities");
        markers[value.hex].setIcon(squawkerror(value)); 
    }
} else
```

Comment: Then split it into two if statement instead of one? Split it out so it only avoids the alert if that is set in local storage? Execute the color marker change regardless of localstorage state..?

Comment: How do you store `alerted` value in the `localstorage` ? And why don't you use a boolean value instead of a string one ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check for alerted *around the alert* and if not set, alert and set it. Next time, no alert will be set and no stored value will be changed.

```html
var alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || false;

if( value.squawk == 7500 || value.squawk == 7600 ||value.squawk == 7700 ){

    console.log(value.hex + " is squawking " + value.squawk);

    if( !alerted ){
        alert(value.hex + " is squawking " + value.squawk + ". This is usually an error in transponder transmission please DO NOT alert the local authorities");
        localStorage.setItem('alerted', true);
    }

    markers[value.hex].setIcon(squawkerror(value));

}
```